How to insert a custom sized image in ckeditor5 using its API?
I am accessing an instance of a webpage's ckEditor like this
const ckEditorElement = document.activeElement;

const ckEditorInstance = ckEditorElement?.ckeditorInstance;

So far I inserted content using insertContent, but the problem is that if I am inserting an <img> element it ignores the width/height styling of it.
const text = '<p>Some text before '
 + <img src="https://www.example.com/someImg200x200.png" width="100" height="100" />
 + ' Some text after</p>';

ckEditorInstance.model.change((writer) => {
    const viewFragment = ckEditorInstance.data.processor.toView(text);
    const modelFragment = ckEditorInstance.data.toModel(viewFragment);
    writer.model.insertContent(modelFragment, ckEditorInstance.model.document.selection);
});

The editor I am trying to do this in has like 40 plugins which include Image, ImageResize, ZendeskImagePlugin, but I could not resolve this issue with the information found in CKEditor5 documentation.

Try style="width:100px;height:100px"

@wOxxOm Thank you! How and why does this work? I spent the whole day yesterday trying to figure this out and it ends up being this simple...

Apparently the editor allows style attribute but not others. It may be a bug or intended behavior.
